# Can I customize TeX/MathJax in Chrome?

Tags: support, mathjax, user-interface

Probably this question belongs to some general SE meta but I don't even know where it is or whether I am eligible to post there, and mostly I am using MO anyway, so if there is another more appropriate place maybe somebody can give a link.

Formulas appear differently in different browsers, mostly because of different fonts I guess, but maybe there are also some subtle formatting differences. So far the best for me, bost visually and in terms of rendering speed, was the way MathJax is handled by [Waterfox](https://www.waterfoxproject.org/); on the other hand I am almost exclusively using Chrome everywhere, so I prefer to stick to it. And in Chrome sometimes rendering of formulas becomes jerky/laggy, especially when editing a question or answer. Also, I like much more fonts and resolution used by Waterfox.

Is there a way to fine-tune various aspects of MathJax/TeX configuration in Chrome?

Comment: You can try to fiddle with settings in the mathjax context menu (in particular, "Math Renderer"), but if it doesn't help, the place to ask is https://groups.google.com/d/forum/mathjax-users .